# How to convert the field name when exporting data from postgres

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to export data from PostgreSQL to Elastic search using jdbc. I have following code in my conf file:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_office"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "useruser"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "D:\logstash-6.0.0\logstash-6.0.0\config\postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from customers"
        # clean_run => true
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "poi_201708"
        document_type => "poi"
        document_id => "%{gid}" # unique id require
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
    # stdout {
    #     codec => rubydebug
    # }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    convert => ["location", "geo_point"]
  }
}
```

In my table, location field type is text. But I want to change it to "geo_location". I know I can change to geo_point after exporting data. But I am trying if it is possible to convert while exporting or not. When I tried above conf file I am getting following error:

```
Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<LogStash::ConfigurationError: translation missing: en.logstash.agent.configuration.invalid_plugin_register>, :backtrace=>["D:/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.6/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:186:in `block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1343:in `each'", "D:/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.6/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:184:in `register'", "D:/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:388:in `register_plugin'", "D:/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:399:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", "D:/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:399:in `register_plugins'", "D:/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:801:in `maybe_setup_out_plugins'", "D:/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:409:in `start_workers'", "D:/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:333:in `run'", "D:/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:293:in `block in start'"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x5acabbfa@D:/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:290 run>"}
[2018-08-14T17:02:06,659][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the field name or convert the column data?

Comment: @Koen I am trying to change the field type from text to geo_point